# ONVIF - fetching recording from cameras

Tags: ip-camera, onvif

I have two network cameras, one made by TVT and one made by Uniview. I'm triggering SD card recording with alarm inputs and I'm trying to fetch recordings from their SD cards. Both manufacturers have their custom protocols that are able to do this, but I have to use ONVIF (according to customer specification).

I've used RTSP (with address I've got from GetRecordings()) with range selection for both these cameras, but it is not quite useful. TVT plays all the recordings from specified time as a continuous stream (I don't know when recordings start and stop if there is more that one) while Uniview only plays first recording from the specified time (if I would want to play second one I guess I would have to calculate length and try playing from next second). This would work well if I could get access to recordings list.

In response to either ONVIF GetRecordings() or FindRecordings() + GetRecordingsSearchResults() both of them are replying with only single item, apparently covering whole recording time span.
Reading ONVIF specification I would expect multiple items in these responses. Am I misinterpreting ONVIF specification or is this behavior some kind of simplification?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how to interpret GetRecordings() or FindRecordings() ONVIF specification / compliance, but it looks like I can use FindEvents with both these cameras and returned results allow me to determine when recordings start and end.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on the edge synchronization feature for cameras. You are correct most cameras don't provide multiple files instead they give an RTSP URL as a single stream and it's hard to interpret them.
One thing I did is I provided start-time and end-time in the OpenRtsp parameters so that after downloading the file up to the limit it gets stopped. Then I convert them into a suitable format.
For handling the file missing error I relied on RTSP itself most cameras give a 500 internal server error when there is no file present inside the camera and you try to download this other simply start and then stop instantly making a 0kb file. You can make a retry mechanism so that if the behavior of the camera is the same every time between a time period just leave this entry it's not inside the camera.
P.S: If you got to know some better way via onvif I would love to know that.